# Would "I feel hunger" be an equivalent to "I'm hungry"?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I found this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81889/copula-copula-and-noun-i-feel-anger-i-feel-angry) on ELL where the OP mentioned "I feel anger." and the answerer [stated the following about it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/81924/80554):

> [...] *I feel anger* typically more usually means you feel someone else's anger, or anger caused by an object or external cause - whereas *I feel angry* only describes your feelings.
>
> Although it is possible that someone can say *I feel anger* to mean something close to *I feel angry* if it's obvious from context that there isn't an external anger.

I want to know if it is the same case for **I feel hunger**, and if it can be said by someone who is hungry as an equivalent to **I am hungry**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many contexts, "I feel *hungry*" would be roughly the same as "I am hungry".  It is slightly dispassionate, as if you are standing outside yourself objectively evaluating your status.

> A:  You want to get something to eat?  There's a good noodle place just around the corner.
>   B:  Yeah, **I feel hungry**.  I could eat.

"I feel *hunger*" is even more dispassionate, and really only makes sense when talking objectively about general situations or motivations.

> I don't eat breakfast.  Yes, **I feel hunger** when I first wake up in the morning, but if I just have something simple like a cup of tea, I'm fine until lunchtime.

In this way it's much the same as "I feel anger", or really any other emotion or sensation.  However, it's probably best not to overuse it as it makes you sound almost robotic, like a machine discussing its moving parts.  Instead use the more common expressions:

> I **am** hungry
>
> I **get/become/grow** hungry
>
> I **feel** hungry

You can also use the noun "hunger" to figuratively describe something for which you have strong passion or desire:

> I have a **hunger** to succeed.  You shouldn't be surprised if I am a millionaire by this time next year.

Or you can use the verb "hunger":

> I **hunger** for success ...

Comment: A great answer that discusses all the related issues about "hunger". Thank you so much, Andrew!